# How to force RTL layout on React Native app? (not working on first load)

Tags: android, react-native

I want my app to be **RTL Only**. I'm using an **android** device and **I'm not testing on iphone for now.**

**No Expo**

**couldn't find a good solution online.** I tried

```
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';
I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
```

in my index.js before AppRegistry and it works but only from second load.
also tried

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;

public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
I18nUtil.getInstance().forceRTL(this,true);
I18nUtil.getInstance().allowRTL(this, true);
```

in MainApplication.java. same thing - LTR on first load.

P.S. **I don't want to RNRestart.**

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change your code in MainApplication.java to

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.i18nmanager.I18nUtil;


public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();

  // other stuff ...

  // FORCE RTL
  I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();
  sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(getApplicationContext(), true);
  sharedI18nUtilInstance.forceRTL(getApplicationContext(), true);
}
```

And also add `android:supportsRtl="true"` attribute to `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.